# Putty refuses connections to all remote servers

Tags: networking, ssh, router, putty

I'm trying to connect to my VPS servers, but putty is giving me connection timeout errors.

I recently got a new broadband connection and for some reasons putty is not working on the new connection, it works totally fine when I use a different network.

I think something is wrong with the router, I have heard that I need to set a portforward but I'm not sure how to do this on this router.

I'm using PTCL broadband, and the name of the router brand is believed to be TENDA.

Here is the screenshot of the router interface: http://prntscr.com/4l47vm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portforward is needed only for incoming connections, not outgoing connections. 
I am suspecting a problem with your putty network configuration (gateway? Proxy?). 
Try to connect to your servers using another tool, like for example TeraTerm Pro.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Peter , actually it's not just putty. I have used a different client on my android phone and same issue. None of the SSH clients are working. I have tested on 2 different PCs and a android phone. But if I connect to a different networking all of the SSH clients work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "different networking"?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant to say that it works fine on my other internet connection.

Comment: And I suppose that the rest of the internet connectivity if fine, isn't it?

Comment: I have reset my router which has fixed the problem, I still can't figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. This can be marked as answered.